# Full Text search on Django Rest Framework only supported for MYSQL?

Tags: django, api, django-rest-framework

Why does Django Rest Framework only support a full text search for MYSQL backend when there is much more capable db like Postgres, I read this and was surprised :/

http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering

"@' Full-text search. (Currently only supported Django's MySQL backend.)"

Know any concrete reason behind this ?

Answer (score 10):

This has changed since @stalk answered. [As of Django 1.10](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/releases/1.10/#full-text-search-for-postgresql), the Django Rest Framework can support PostgreSQL as well.

And since `django.contrib.postgres` provides the same [`__search` interface](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/postgres/search/#the-search-lookup) as MySQL does, you can connect your API to Postgres using the same setup as for MySQL:

- Add `django.contrib.postgres` to your `INSTALLED_APPS`.
- In your view, use the `@` symbol to mark the full-text search fields:

  ```
  search_fields = ('@title', '@description')
  ```

In fact, it sounds like Django's full-text search support for MySQL is either deprecated or is at least changing, according to the deprecation note on the Django docs link in @stalk's original answer. That note links to the following explanation, which also contains example code for replacing it:

> The search lookup, which supports MySQL only and is extremely limited in features, is deprecated. Replace it with a custom lookup...

I apologize, I don't have enough reputation to post additional direct links.

Answer (score 3):

That is because django-rest-framework use django's `__search`.

From current latest commit in master of [django-rest-framework](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/blob/ab213cbc41114ec9417630d5298546102a706b96/rest_framework/filters.py#L90):

```
def construct_search(self, field_name):
    if field_name.startswith('^'):
        return "%s__istartswith" % field_name[1:]
    elif field_name.startswith('='):
        return "%s__iexact" % field_name[1:]
    elif field_name.startswith('@'):
        return "%s__search" % field_name[1:]
    else:
        return "%s__icontains" % field_name
```

And [django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#search) tells about `__search`(boolean full-text search):

```
Note this is only available in MySQL and requires direct manipulation of the database 
to add the full-text index. By default Django uses BOOLEAN MODE for full text searches.
See the MySQL documentation for additional details.
```